# Htaccess redirect from subdir to Domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm stuck with an htacces project. On my old domain i've:
olddomain.eu/en/[uris]
olddomain.eu/de/[uris]

Now i need to split the sites to different domains without losing the indexing so i created this htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^de(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^en(.*)$ http://www.domain.eu/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

The only problem is it now redirect like this:
**olddomain.eu/de/test.html** to *www.domein.de* instead of **www.domein.de/test.html**

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `RewriteLog` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks close but for correctness you can try this regex:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^de/(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ http://www.domain.eu/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```